# php artisan serve error : require(): Failed opening

Tags: php, laravel, windows-10

I tried to follow the tutorials one by one and still have some errors.
I installed php successfully(v 7.0.30), composer(v 1.6.5) also works just fine. with laravel I managed to start a new project. but I am getting error while I want to run 
the error says

> PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open str
>   eam: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand\artisan on line 18
>
> Warning: require(C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand\artisan on line 18
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand/vendor/a
>   utoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand\artisan on
>   line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand/vendor/autolo
>   ad.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\davranbek\rand\artisan on line
>   18

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. thanks in advance

Comment: How did you installed Laravel? Looks like no vedor dir. Run `composer install` in laravel dir.

And Here is the instalation process for Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation

Comment: A file to be loaded for execution by the PHP interpreter is not available. Either the file is missing or the path is misconfigured. Both typically a configuration issue. Double check the file is there and/or all paths are configured properly. If you're clue-less, enable a step-debugger and learn more or if you're even more clue-less, re-install from a clean system. Maybe the second time it just works then you won't need to learn about what you did wrong. In any case for the second time, keep an installation log by your own in which your write down each step and the commands used. That helps.

Comment: @Pyton I installed Laravel with the command "composer global require "laravel/installer"" and I did no further more because I found the text quite confusing and nothing was mentioned on the video tutorial

Comment: @hakre, I am not sure how to set the paths file. Could you please give me where to set and what to write in there if you don't mind. Thank you

Comment: I can't tell you, that would be configuration files to edit for the application you installed. Maybe start from scratch? Also double check if the operating system you're using is supported.

Comment: @DavranbekRozmetov Have a look [here],(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installation) mind the Laravel version you are using and the page I gave you (selecte the correct version on the top right corner) and you can see how to install it. Also, laravel is the easiest thing to install, I don't understand why is confusing to you, maybe you have 0 knowledge about composer but that is not Laravel.